# Animating custom NSView drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I want a simple application with 2 NSViews when a user clicks at a button a NSView hides and the other shows, when it shows i want to animate it like the tools button in office, but i can't figure out how to, if anyone has tried this or somethig similar it would be great. If you don't have a answer yuo coukd help with the documentatio required to archive this or telling me the properties that i have to animate.

I already try animating the frame

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(showFader:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)showFader: (NSTimer*)timer {
    [[customer_s_view animator] setFrame:[customer_f_view frame]];
    }

- (IBAction)searchfull:(id)sender{
    if([customer_s_view isHidden]){
    [customer_s_view setHidden:NO];
        [customer_s_view setFrame:NSMakeRect(400.0, 700.0, 1, 1)];
[customer_f_view setHidden:YES];
}
```

Help, this is for a demo that i have to show this monday

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it can help you but I use [FTutils](https://github.com/neror/ftutils) to do view animations

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but i'm developing a desktop application